# Increment Insert Versus Map/Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Let's say you have a collection of documents that are structured as follows:

```
{ username: "jones",
    likes: 20,
    text: "Hello world!"
  }
```

Furthermore assume that the application you're building needs to display statistics on total number of likes per user.  Mongodb documentation shows that you can accomplish this with a Map/Reduce function like this one:

```
function() {
    emit( this.username, {count: 1, likes: this.likes} );
  }
```

However, it seems more intuitive to me to simply increment a "Like" counter each time I insert a new document into the database.  This doesn't require traversing the entire collection the way that Map/Reduce would.  It updates the counter immediately rather than the next time the Map/Reduce process runs.  And the architecture seems simpler.

Can someone please explain in an answer why a Map/Reduce function is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proposed MapReduce solution in the MongoDB docs is intended to be more generic. That is, if you're interested in `stat(x)` for some function `stat()` for each record `x` and you didn't know you were going to be interested in `stat` at the time you set up your data set, then MapReduce provides a nice *a posteriori* way to aggregate such a statistic across the records.

If you *already know* you'll always be interested in `stat(x)` for every `x`, then by all means do as much precomputation and storage as you feel is appropriate.

I can imagine, though, that there is some tradeoff between the time to index and search for the stats vs. just computing them each time they are needed. If the data set became gigantic (I'm not sure of a good estimate for gigantic here) then it could, theoretically, be more advantageous to just MapReduce-compute it every time, because the wait time for retrieval would be about as bad.

I'm guessing though that the size of the data at which MapReduce wins that tradeoff is preposterously large, and even at that if you wanted to do more things with the data post-calculation it may not really be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a very clear explanation.  To put gigantic into context, let's assume we're talking about the backend datastore for Stackoverflow.  Would tallying votes be an example where you would advise using MapReduce even though you already know that you need to aggregate votes? Or does it have to be a Google-scale problem before that tradeoff becomes relevant.  Just an academic question at this point.  My app is rather small and so I'll precompute my stats as per your answer.

Comment: My guess, with nothing much more to go on other than some casual posts about what Hadoop's use cases should be, is that it would need to be in the hundreds of TBs before MapReduce would win over retrieval. It may also win if the data happens to already be distributed and stored in different places for whatever reasons. Here are some links: [What Hadoop Is Not](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIsNot) and [Hadoop Dont's](http://www.databonanza.com/2011/05/hadoop-donts-what-not-to-do-to-harvest.html)

Comment: there is no collection size where mapReduce would be similar in speed to a query against the collection, especially an indexed one. MapReduce in MongoDB is slow, in javascript, has to go through each document, has to run single-threaded, has to convert BSON to JSON back to BSON, etc.  Plus you can do this query with aggregation framework (in 2.2) faster than mapReduce, but pre-computing and querying directly will *always* be faster.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce isn't designed for ad-hoc, live queries. It's slow. It's more of a batch processing mechanism, so your proposed design would be much more efficient performance wise.